# R code to test the difference between coefficients of regressors from a multinomial logit regression

Tags: r, coefficients, multinomial, regression-testing

I have the following multinomial logit regression

```
FLAG ~ Cash + Debt + Other variables
```

Where FLAG is a dummy with three levels, that distinguishes three different types of firms, while Cash and Debt are some variables regarding those firms.
The results of the regression are the following

```
Variables         Type 0 vs Type 1          Type 0 vs Type 2
Cash                  0.543***                   0.321***
Debt                  -0.124***                  0.452***
```

I now want to test whether the difference between these coefficients is statistically significant (in this case, between 0.543 and 0.321, and between -0.124 and 0.452)
I know I have to use the Wald test (as it was used in some papers I looked at, that performed the same analysis), but I don't know how to implement it on R.
What's the R code to implement a Wald test of the difference between the coefficients of the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using the `Chile` data from the `carData` package.

```r
data(Chile, package="carData")
mod <- nnet::multinom(vote ~ sex + I(income/10000), data=Chile)
#> # weights:  16 (9 variable)
#> initial  value 3395.034890 
#> iter  10 value 3105.730891
#> final  value 3043.519706 
#> converged
summary(mod)
#> Call:
#> nnet::multinom(formula = vote ~ sex + I(income/10000), data = Chile)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>   (Intercept)          sexM I(income/10000)
#> N    1.212092  0.5676465119      0.02101608
#> U    1.430206 -0.2235933346     -0.06761914
#> Y    1.477171 -0.0003631522      0.02018734
#> 
#> Std. Errors:
#>   (Intercept)      sexM I(income/10000)
#> N   0.1326298 0.1655421      0.02108768
#> U   0.1352691 0.1738994      0.02478598
#> Y   0.1300724 0.1657089      0.02108419
#> 
#> Residual Deviance: 6087.039 
#> AIC: 6105.039
```

Let's say that in the model above, you wanted to compare the coefficients for `sexM` for the categories `N` and `U`.  You could save the variance-covariance matrix of the estimators in `v` and the coefficients themselves in a vector called `b`.

```
v <- vcov(mod)
b <- c(t(coef(mod)))
names(b) <- rownames(v)
```

Then, you could create the relevant z-statistic by dividing the difference in coefficients by its standard error (the square root of the sum of the two variances minus two times the covariance of the relevant parameters):

```
z_wt <- (b["N:sexM"] - b["U:sexM"])/sqrt(v["N:sexM", "N:sexM"] + v["U:sexM", "U:sexM"] - 2*v["N:sexM", "U:sexM"])
```

Then, you could use `pnorm()` to calculate the p-value.

```
2*pnorm(abs(z_wt), lower.tail=FALSE)
#>       N:sexM 
#> 1.255402e-12
```

Another option would be to just change the reference category.  For example if I wanted the `U`-`N` comparison, I could change the reference to either `U` or `N` and re-estimate the model:

```
Chile$vote2 <- relevel(Chile$vote, "U")
mod2 <- nnet::multinom(vote2 ~ sex + I(income/10000), data=Chile, maxit=1000)
#> # weights:  16 (9 variable)
#> initial  value 3395.034890 
#> iter  10 value 3081.860210
#> final  value 3043.519705 
#> converged
z_wt2 <- coef(mod2)["N", "sexM"]/summary(mod2)$standard.errors["N", "sexM"]

2*pnorm(abs(z_wt2), lower.tail=FALSE)
#> [1] 1.256475e-12
```

Note that the two p-values are very close (though not exactly the same) as are the differences in the coefficients from the two methods, which are not printed.

I wrote a package called `factorplot` which will calculate all of the pairwise differences for a single variable's coefficients in the MNL model:

```
library(factorplot)
f <- factorplot(mod, variable="sexM")
print(f)
#>       Difference    SE p.val
#> A - N     -0.568 0.166 0.001
#> A - U      0.224 0.174 0.199
#> N - U      0.791 0.111 0.000
#> A - Y      0.000 0.166 0.998
#> N - Y      0.568 0.098 0.000
#> U - Y     -0.223 0.112 0.046
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This method is a bit easier and is based on the same calculations I proposed in the first method above.